# How do stats affect to-hit percentages?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

My soldiers have an **Aim** stat and a **Defense** stat. Sometimes, I've got things like smoke grenades which claim to give you *+20 defense* and the like.

What does this actually mean in terms of chance to hit? Is a point of aim or defense worth 1% to hit, or some such?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Aim** and **Defense** are pretty simple. As you suggest, they're simply lacking a % sign.

**Aim** is your base chance to hit. A rookie's starting 65% **Aim** means a 65% chance to hit.

**Defense** is also pretty simple: 10 **Defense** means 10% less chance to hit.

In this way, you can think of Cover as providing **Defense**, and standing in a smoke cloud makes you 20% less likely to be hit, hence, 20 **Defense**. (Incidentally, 65% base **Aim** and -20% for low cover is why most Rookies have a 45% chance to hit sectoids in your first couple of missions).

Additionally (thought not a stat per se), different weapons get different range bonuses, which increase or decrease your chance to hit. Shotguns can get up to 37% bonus chance to hit at point blank, and Sniper Rifles actually get a penalty if you're too close.

Comment: Seems like most guns except sniper rifles do get an aim penalty at range.  I'd love to know what those thresholds are in numbers.  Side note:  Sick of getting headshotted by a plasma pistol from 40 meters.  =(