# XCOM sniper cover bonus damage to aim?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

So when a sniper is in half cover, it can treat it as full cover with the Low Profile perk. Does that include reducing its aim according to full cover, or does that only apply to defense?

Comment: None of your units have their aim reduced when they are in full cover.  Any aim reduction comes from the targetted enemy being in full cover.  Therefore, the sniper will not take an aim reduction from having the Low Profile perk.

Comment: @JasonBerkan you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shooter's cover does not impact aim in any way, only target's cover does.

Comment: In [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87333/how-do-stats-affect-to-hit-percentages) article, it talks about covering reducing your chances of hitting the enemy, due to the cover caused by being in the cloud of a smoke grenade. Is this not correct?

Comment: @JShoe It says "standing in smoke makes you 20% less likely to **be hit**", i.e. smoke decreases enemy's aim, if you are a target. Whether a shooter is in smoke, or if there is smoke between the shooter and the target, is irrelevant.

Comment: Though it is possible to "misplace" your smoke grenade such that it covers you and an enemy unit.  In that case, the enemy unit would get a +20% to their defense, which is a straight -20% to your aim to hit that enemy.